# searching for a word in a text file

Tags: java

I have written the code below.  It is a simple method that compares an argument sig to a dictionary.  I have been able to make the code work and if there is a match it will return the first line in the dictionary.

But I am struggling to get the code to loop.  I do not know how many lines there are in the dictionary and if I did get the loop to work how do I prevent the method from keep reading the first line in the dictionary.  I was wondering if I should try and do this recursively.  Any tips?  Thank you.

```
public static Set<String> signature2Words(String sig) throws FileNotFoundException{
    try (Scanner s = new Scanner(new File("c:/Users/Green/documents/dictionary.txt")).useDelimiter("\\s*-\\s*")) {

        String dictionary = new String(s.nextLine());
        System.out.println(dictionary);
        System.out.println(wordToSignature(dictionary));

        if (sig.compareToIgnoreCase(wordToSignature(dictionary)) == 0){
            System.out.println("match");
        }

        Set<String> set = new HashSet<>();
        set.add(dictionary);
        return set ;
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need of recursion here. A simple `while()` loop and a `break` should do the work:

```
try (Scanner s = new Scanner(file).useDelimiter("\\s*-\\s*")) {

        while (s.hasNextLine()) {
            String dictionary = s.nextLine();
            System.out.println(dictionary);
            if (sig.compareToIgnoreCase(wordToSignature(dictionary)) == 0) {
                System.out.println("match");
                break;
            }
        }
        Set<String> set = new HashSet<>();
        set.add(dictionary);
        return set;
    }
```